# How do I use a shell-script as Chrome Native Messaging host application

Tags: json, bash, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

How do you process a Chrome Native Messaging API-call with a bash script?

I succeeded in doing it with python with [this example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/)

Sure I can call `bash` from the python code with `subprocess`, but is it possible to skip python and process the message in `bash` directly?

The **problematic** part is reading the JSON serialized message into a variable. The message is serialized using JSON, UTF-8 encoded and is preceded with 32-bit message length in native byte order through stdin.

`echo $*` only outputs:
`chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/`

Also something like

```
read
echo $REPLY
```

doesn't output anything. No sign of the JSON message. Python uses `struct.unpack` for this. Can that be done in `bash`?

Comment: @heinst "write a shell script and use curl" - and how would that exactly solve this problem...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to not use (bash) shell scripts as a native messaging host, because bash is too limited to be useful.

`read` without any parameters reads a whole line before terminating, while the [native messaging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol) specifies that the first four bytes specify the length of the following message (in native byte order).

Bash is a terrible tool for processing binary data. An improved version of your `read` command would specify the `-n N` parameter to stop reading after `N` characters (note: not bytes) and `-r` to remove some processing. E.g. the following would store the first four characters in a variable called `var_prefix`:

```bash
IFS= read -rn 4 var_prefix
```

Even if you assume that this stores the first four bytes in the variable (it does not!), then you have to convert the bytes to an integer. Did I already mention that bash automatically drops all NUL bytes? This characteristics makes Bash utterly worthless for being a fully capable native messaging host.

You could cope with this shortcoming by ignoring the first few bytes, and start parsing the result when you spot a `{` character, the beginning of the JSON-formatted request. After this, you have to read all input until the end of the input is found. You need a JSON parser that stops reading input when it encounters the end of the JSON string. Good luck with writing that.

Generating output is a easier, just use `echo -n` or [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf).

Here is a minimal example that assumes that the input ends with a `}`, reads it (without processing) and replies with a result. Although this demo works, I **strongly recommend to not use bash, but a richer (scripting) language such as Python or C++.**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Loop forever, to deal with chrome.runtime.connectNative
while IFS= read -r -n1 c; do
    # Read the first message
    # Assuming that the message ALWAYS ends with a },
    # with no }s in the string. Adopt this piece of code if needed.
    if [ "$c" != '}' ] ; then
        continue
    fi

    message='{"message": "Hello world!"}'
    # Calculate the byte size of the string.
    # NOTE: This assumes that byte length is identical to the string length!
    # Do not use multibyte (unicode) characters, escape them instead, e.g.
    # message='"Some unicode character:\u1234"'
    messagelen=${#message}

    # Convert to an integer in native byte order.
    # If you see an error message in Chrome's stdout with
    # "Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is ... bytes long.",
    # then just swap the order, i.e. messagelen1 <-> messagelen4 and
    # messagelen2 <-> messagelen3
    messagelen1=$(( ($messagelen      ) & 0xFF ))               
    messagelen2=$(( ($messagelen >>  8) & 0xFF ))               
    messagelen3=$(( ($messagelen >> 16) & 0xFF ))               
    messagelen4=$(( ($messagelen >> 24) & 0xFF ))               

    # Print the message byte length followed by the actual message.
    printf "$(printf '\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x' \
        $messagelen1 $messagelen2 $messagelen3 $messagelen4)%s" "$message"

done
```

Comment: Great answer. I was afraid of this. On the other hand we shouldn't try to hit a _nail_ with a _saw_. Python is fine, and once again proven: **batteries included**

Answer (score 1):

The message reading and writing can be done in pure bash, and without using any subshells.

The tricky part is reading the first 4 bytes as a number. This can be done by setting `LC_ALL=C`, which will make bash treat each byte as a separate character, and using the following options for `read`:

- `-r` to prevent backslash processing
- `-d ''` to have `read` return 0 after reading a null byte
- `-n 1` to read one character (=byte) at a time

We also use the default output variable `REPLY`, which prevents whitespace stripping from the input.

To convert a character `C` to its numeric value, we use `printf %d "'C"`.

After we calculate the length by applying the appropriate bit shifts to the values above, we can use `read -r -N LEN` to read exactly that many bytes from the input.

```bash
LC_ALL=C
readmsg() {
    # return non-zero if fewer than 4 bytes of input available
    # or if message is shorter than length specified by first 
    # 4 bytes of input
    # otherwise, set the variable $msg and return 0

    local -i i n len=0
    local REPLY
    for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do
        read -r -d '' -n 1 || return
        printf -v n %d "'$REPLY"
        len+='n<<i*8'
    done
    read -r -N "$len" && ((${#REPLY}==len)) && msg=$REPLY
}

sendmsg() {
    local x
    # the message length as 4 hex bytes
    printf -v x %08X "${#1}"
    # write each of the 4 bytes
    printf %b "\x${x:6:2}\x${x:4:2}\x${x:2:2}\x${x:0:2}"
    # write the message itself
    printf %s "$1"
}

while readmsg; do
    # do_something "$msg"
    response='{"echo": "foo"}'
    sendmsg "$response"
done
```

Comment: `spellcheck` warns for `printf -v n %d "'$REPLY"` [fixed by `len+=$((n<<i*8))`](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1atbq77/comment/kqw7ssw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Working example modified to echo input https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_bash_standalone.sh.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `shellcheck` and that the warning is for the line _after_ the `printf -v` one? If so, changing  `len='...'` to `len=$((...))` does not matter here because the `len` variable was created with `local -i` so all assignments already undergo arithmetic expansion.

Comment: You can run `spellcheck` on your original code yourself to observe the warning. I linked to where I got the code to get rid of the warning, and where I adjusted your code to echo back input to the client.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_bash.sh) is how I wound up doing this in Bash, with GNU Coreutils `head` and `tail` (which do create subprocesses), to echo input back to client from host.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Native Messaging host
set -x
set -o posix
getMessage() {
  # https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2023-06/msg00036.html
  # length=$(busybox dd iflag=fullblock bs=4 count=1 | busybox od -An -td4)
  # message=$(busybox dd iflag=fullblock bs=$((length)) count=1)
  length=$(head -q -z --bytes=4 -| od -An -td4 -)
  message=$(head -q -z --bytes=$((length)) -)
  sendMessage "$message"
}
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777120
sendMessage() {
  message="$*"
  # Calculate the byte size of the string.
  # NOTE: This assumes that byte length is identical to the string length!
  # Do not use multibyte (unicode) characters, escape them instead, e.g.
  # message='"Some unicode character:\u1234"'
  messagelen=${#message}
  # Convert to an integer in native byte order.
  # If you see an error message in Chrome's stdout with
  # "Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is ... bytes long.",
  # then just swap the order, i.e. messagelen1 <-> messagelen4 and
  # messagelen2 <-> messagelen3
  messagelen1=$(((messagelen) & 0xFF))
  messagelen2=$(((messagelen >> 8) & 0xFF))
  messagelen3=$(((messagelen >> 16) & 0xFF))
  messagelen4=$(((messagelen >> 24) & 0xFF))
  # Print the message byte length followed by the actual message.
  printf "$(printf '\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x' \
    $messagelen1 $messagelen2 $messagelen3 $messagelen4)%s" "$message"
}

main() {
  while true; do
    getMessage
  done
}

main
```