# how to take path location from textbox and put it in batch

Tags: batch-file, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

Hello guys im trying to make an extension that open any exe on user computer by simply textbox.user will write the path of exe he wants to open and i need to take that path to batch file and run it is that possible if that so how?
my current batch file only open one path but i want it to take paths from user and open that exe on path location

Comment: Batch can't interact with GUIs.

Comment: It _is_ possible with a Native Host module, but the question is horribly broad with no effort demonstrated.

Comment: yes im using native messaging host how is it possible?

Comment: Demonstrate what you've done already (or what you can do without help), and what specifically is the problem.

Comment: Why not output the path to a text file? You can use batch to get the path in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745405/native-messaging-extension-connectnative-not-working-on-localhost i have this it calls batch file with messaging and my batch file only open one exe but i want it to open any exe depends on the input

Comment: @Xan you mean i get the input from textbox written to texfile and batch read textfile?

Comment: @darkfang Probably because there is no write access to the fs.

Comment: @darkfang how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Native Messaging does not allow you to pass command line parameters. It will only allow communication using the [Native Messaging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol) (length + JSON-enconded message).

So you need to make a single native host that is able to read an incoming message, decode it and execute the command you want, i.e.:

```
// Extension side
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('native.app.id.here', { command: "calc.exe" });
```

and then the app will receive, through STDIN, the length of the message + `{"command":"calc.exe"}`

Actually writing code that will decode that message using batch scripting is a *terrible* idea, but doable in principe. You should probably write an actual program in a language with support for JSON manipulation to handle this. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587091/chrome-extension-message-passing-to-batch-file).

Comment: thank you so i should not use batch file to open local exe

Comment: You can, but if you want to pass data (like which file to launch), batch is a poor choice.

Comment: is it possible with c++?

Comment: Certainly. It's just reading from `cin` _according to the protocol_, then you'll need to parse the string somehow - shouldn't be difficult if you follow a fixed format, and then `fork`/`exec` to spawn a new process and execute it. Sorry, but actual implementation is beyond the scope of my answer. If you have more concrete questions about it, make a new question. Actually, if someone makes such a generic "launcher" native host and leaves it open-source it will be very useful.

Comment: yeah its hard to imagine im just intern and they gave me this project and i have no idea