# Chrome sendNativeMessage with Batch, CMD or PowerShell

Tags: google-chrome-app

Google provides an example of calling native executables [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples). The actual "executable" is a .BAT file which calls python. I wanted to see if I could just run a .bat file with some typical OS or maybe even PowerShell commands. According to [the help](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging) the executable needs to return UTF-8 JSON so I replaced the call to python with the following command:

```
TYPE %~dp0\SAMPLE.json
```

Where `SAMPLE.json` is a UTF-8 file with some JSON content.

Needless to say it does not work:

```
Error when communicating with the native messaging host.
```

According to the help it could be because of message size or text vs. binary output modes. I know of no way to get a batch file to "talk binary".

Is there any way to get Chrome to talk to text based CLI utilities like batch files, powershell...?

Comment: Relevant: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587091/chrome-extension-message-passing-to-batch-file), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764657/how-do-i-use-a-shell-script-as-chrome-native-messaging-host-application). In short: it's not a good idea to limit your tools - if you need to talk to an existing CLI utility, make a "proxy" native host using tools that are fit for the job.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I want to make a GUI for PowerShell so I want to talk as directly as possible to powershell.exe and can't much see the point of making a proxy if there's a direct way.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever figured something out, Marc. I think I agree with Xan's comment that PowerShell, etc may not be the best fit, but it certainly would be convenient for certain scenarios.

Comment: Nope, gave that one up as a bad job.

Comment: As did Google: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html